# how to ban/kick members with Discord.js Discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

can someone help me ban/kick members with custom prefixes
with Discord.js V 14.5 and I'm using node js

Comment: Which part of that are you stuck on?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-ban-a-user

Please check the documentation, it doesn't take a lot of time.

Comment: While this doesn't suit as an answer, I agree with pointing the OP to the resources instead of spoon-feeding code